# How to associate events, metrics and source-level results for profiling a pyCUDA program using nvvp

Tags: profiling, pycuda, nvvp

When I try to profile my pyCUDA application using nvvp, it works for the most part. I can click on "Examine GPU Usage" and view a number of analysis results / suggestions for my code, such as "Low Compute / Memcpy Efficiency."

However, everytime that nvvp runs the program to perform an analysis, I see the following warning.

> Some collected events, metrics or source-level results could not be associated with the session timeline. This may prevent event, metric and source-level results from being assigned to some kernels.

It looks like I might be able to get more detailed analysis if I do something to fix this. Does anyone know how to associate "collected events, metrics or source-level results with the session timeline"?

Answer (score 1):

As seems in profiler documentation:

> ◦The Visual Profiler cannot correctly import profiler data generated by nvprof when the option --kernels kernel-filter is used. Visual Profiler reports a warning, "Some collected events or source-level results could not be associated with the session timeline." One workaround is to use the nvprof option --kernels :::1 to profile the first invocation for all kernels.

so you can try change this option